# How to debug Microsoft Excel Add-In / Plugin Manifest File

Tags: ms-office

I am trying to make a custom plugin in Excel.  I am getting an error in debug run and it doesn't show me what the error is so I can't debug it:

[image]

Here is my entire manifest, as you can see, it's impossible to debug just by looking at it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>0311be29-0152-4f77-bd8c-0f093f5b4b97</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="MyProjectExcelPlugin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="MyProject Excel Plugin" />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/Button32x32.png" />

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="MyProject.GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="MyProject.GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="MyProject.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="MyProject.FunctionFile.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="MyProject.Tab">
              <Group id="Group.Settings">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                <Label resid="Group.Settings.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <!--Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized 
                  Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX 
                  Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS-->
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="WG.Group1.Icon_16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="WG.Group1.Icon_32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="WG.Group1.Icon_80" />
                </Icon>
                <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu"-->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                  <Label resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                    <Title resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource-->
                    <Description resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane
                  Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>openControlRoom</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.ConfigButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                  <Label resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                    <Title resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource-->
                    <Description resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ConfigButtonTaskPane</TaskpaneId>
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane-->
                    <SourceLocation resid="MyProject.ConfigPane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.LoginButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                  <Label resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                    <Title resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource-->
                    <Description resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>LoginButtonTaskPane</TaskpaneId>
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane-->
                    <SourceLocation resid="MyProject.LoginPane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.RunBotButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                  <Label resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource-->
                    <Title resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource-->
                    <Description resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>RunBotButtonTaskPane</TaskpaneId>
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane-->
                    <SourceLocation resid="MyProject.RunBotPane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Group id="Group.Run">
                <Label resid="Group.Run.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="WG.Group3.Icon_16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="WG.Group3.Icon_32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="WG.Group3.Icon_80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.FavConfigButton">
                  <Label resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>FavConfigButtonTaskPane</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="MyProject.FavConfigPane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.Fav1Button">
                  <Label resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Label" />
                    <Description resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Fav1Start</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.Fav2Button">
                  <Label resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Label" />
                    <Description resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Fav2Start</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="MyProject.Fav3Button">
                  <Label resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Label" />
                    <Description resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Fav3Start</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="MyProject.Tab.Label" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/kPzt2GZ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/kPzt2GZ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/kPzt2GZ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/Uhn7nii.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/Uhn7nii.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.ConfigButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/Uhn7nii.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/e587PJJ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/e587PJJ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.LoginButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/e587PJJ.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/0rsXZoN.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/0rsXZoN.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.RunBotButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/0rsXZoN.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.AutoTriggerButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/RJ5J6MyProject.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.AutoTriggerButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/RJ5J6MyProject.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.AutoTriggerButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/RJ5J6MyProject.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav1Button.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav2Button.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.Fav3Button.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/VljYaEX.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_16" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/IPoJIoO.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_32" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/IPoJIoO.png" />
        <bt:Image id="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Icon_80" DefaultValue="https://i.imgur.com/IPoJIoO.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://www.google.com" />
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WG.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Panels/TaskPane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.ConfigPane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Panels/ConfigPane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.LoginPane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Panels/LoginPane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.RunBotPane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Panels/RunBotPane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="MyProject.FavConfigPane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Panels/ConfigFavPane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="MyProject.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="MyProject" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Label" DefaultValue="Control Room" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.ConfigButton.Label" DefaultValue="Config" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.LoginButton.Label" DefaultValue="Login" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.RunBotButton.Label" DefaultValue="Run Bot" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.AutoTrigger.Label" DefaultValue="Auto Trigger" />
        <bt:String id="Group.Settings.Label" DefaultValue="Main" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Tab.Group2Label" DefaultValue="Bots" />
        <bt:String id="Group.Run.Label" DefaultValue="Favorite" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Tab.Label" DefaultValue="MyProject" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav1Button.Label" DefaultValue="Favorite 1" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav2Button.Label" DefaultValue="Favorite 2" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav3Button.Label" DefaultValue="Favorite 3" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Label" DefaultValue="Config Favorite" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="MyProject.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="MyProject" />
        <bt:String id="WG.Group1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Important buttons to use MyProject" />
        <bt:String id="WG.Group2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Config and run bots" />
        <bt:String id="WG.Group3.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Setup and run Favorites" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.ControlRoomButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Open the Control Room" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.ConfigButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to config connection settings" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.LoginButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to login with your account" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.RunBotButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to run a bot" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.AutoTriggerButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to setup auto trigger" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav1Button.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Run your Favorite bot #1" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav2Button.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Run your Favorite bot #2" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.Fav3Button.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Run your Favorite bot #3" />
        <bt:String id="MyProject.FavConfigButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Config your Favorite bots" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can only debug this add-on from within Visual Studio. Are you debugging from within Visual Studio? (Your question contains no informationa bout how you're trying to debug; it just mentions *debug run* and *Excel*.)

Comment: I am definitely running this add-on from visual studio.  I am not sure what other information I should include?  Please clarify.